# Annotate images in pascal voc xml

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I need a tool to annotate images with a rectangular bounding box. The output is going to be in pascal voc xml format. Annotations and images will be part of a training dataset used by a convolutional neural net to do object detection. I will annotate the images manually myself.

I've considered the following tools but they don't support pascal-voc.

[Labelme](http://labelme.csail.mit.edu/Release3.0/), [Sloth](http://sloth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), [Pilab](https://code.google.com/p/pilab-annotator/), [No name](http://blog.csdn.net/wongslawski/article/details/40667027)

Is there a annotation tool that will save me time?

Comment: I voted to close, because this is a request/recommendation for a tool. Maybe you better ask this in SoftwareRecommendations StackExchange. See also here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question

Comment: I respectfully suggest that managing deep learning data sets efficiently is not the same as looking for a pdf recommendation tool.

Comment: You are not asking about managing big data sets efficiently; you ask about a tool to annotate images. You did not show any research on looking for such a tool yourself, nor provided any example, nor shown what your challenges are. Please improve your question.

Comment: As I said in my original question, I am using convolutional neural nets which is deep learning.

Comment: I wish to find a Pascal VOC specification, but the link i've found is broken. Can you pass me some working link, please?

Comment: Did you find any way to annotate your dataset ? i am looking to write a script my self, but couldn't find Pascal VOC specification. I have labeled images my self be defining regions (min/max, x/y) ?

Comment: @user3001937 I picked sloth for annotating images. It generates json as output. I wrote some code that converts json to pascal voc xml. You can see the code at the bottom (see accepted answer below). The pascal voc spec is fairly straightforward. Take a look at some existing pascal voc xml files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This python code snippet will convert Sloth json to pascal voc xml.

```
  def make_anno():
    zind = 0
    for z in data:
        print zind
        filename = data[zind]["filename"]
        print filename
        head, tail = os.path.split(filename)
        basename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(tail)    
        f = open(basename + '.xml','w') 
        line = "<annotation>" + '\n'
        f.write(line)
        line = '\t\t<folder>' + "folder" + '</folder>' + '\n'
        f.write(line)
        line = '\t\t<filename>' + tail + '</filename>' + '\n'
        f.write(line)
        line = '\t\t<source>\n\t\t<database>Source</database>\n\t</source>\n'
        f.write(line)
        im=Image.open('/home/location/VOCdevkit/newdataset/img/' + tail)
        (width, height) = im.size
        line = '\t<size>\n\t\t<width>'+ str(width) + '</width>\n\t\t<height>' + str(height) + '</height>\n\t'
        line += '\t<depth>Unspecified</depth>\n\t</size>'
        f.write(line)
        line = '\n\t<segmented>Unspecified</segmented>'
        f.write(line)
        ind = 0
        for i in data[zind]["annotations"]:
            line = '\n\t<object>'
            line += '\n\t\t<name>Name</name>\n\t\t<pose>Unspecified</pose>'
            line += '\n\t\t<truncated>Unspecified</truncated>\n\t\t<difficult>Unspecified</difficult>'
            xmin = (data[zind]["annotations"][ind]["x"])
            line += '\n\t\t<bndbox>\n\t\t\t<xmin>' + str(xmin) + '</xmin>'
            ymin = (data[zind]["annotations"][ind]["y"])
            line += '\n\t\t\t<ymin>' + str(ymin) + '</ymin>'
            width = (data[zind]["annotations"][ind]["width"])
            height = (data[zind]["annotations"][ind]["height"])
            xmax = xmin + width
            ymax = ymin + height
            line += '\n\t\t\t<xmax>' + str(xmax) + '</xmax>'
            line += '\n\t\t\t<ymax>' + str(ymax) + '</ymax>'
            line += '\n\t\t</bndbox>'
            line += '\n\t</object>'     
            f.write(line)
            ind +=1
            f.close()
        zind +=1
```

Answer (score 9):

Please refer to my github:
https://github.com/tzutalin/ImageNet_Utils

How to annotate images :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p0nR2YsCY_U

Comment: Does pascal voc format accepts rotated rectangular annotations? I want to detect scratches but if I dont rotate the rectangle, I will get too much background when scratch is horizontal or vertical.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there are no tools that output your desired format. You might want to use a tool that outputs `xml` in a different format, and transform that. Not ideal, but will probably work.

You could, for example, build an `xslt` to transform the `xml` output of your tools to the Pascal VOC xml standard.